# turn string containing arguments into an array with python

Tags: python, string, list, arguments

I have this python script that takes arguments as strings separated by "," but I cannot just split it because there are some arguments that contain ",". The input is something like this:

```
"hello, how are you","how old are you"
```

and I want to get them as:

```
["hello, how are you","how old are you"]
```

Comment: So is your input actually a single string `'"hello, how are you","how old are you"'`, because as you wrote it it is already a tuple of 2 strings...?

Comment: yes it is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your string looks like csv, maybe you could use the csv module.

```
import csv
my_str = '"hello, how are you","how old are you"'
my_csv = [my_str] # Wrap in a list because the csv module expects it
csv_reader = csv.reader(my_csv)
final_array = next(csv_reader)
```

Should output:

> ['hello, how are you','how old are you']

Answer (score 1):

Without using csv module

```
my_str = '"hello, how are you","how old are you"'
my_str = my_str.split('"')[1::2]
print(my_str)
```

Outputs:

> ['hello, how are you', 'how old are you']